# Maintaining jQuery order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery code, I am having trouble with keeping the correct order of execution. I looked around and found out that using `setTimeout()` is an option but I am not sure where to use. The current structure of the code is like below with `setTimeout()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search-submit').on('click', function(){
    var keyword = $('#search-input').val();
    $(".loading").show();

    setTimeout(function() {
      if(){
        //some conditions and calls to post
      }
      $(".loading").hide();
    }, 0);
   }
  }
```

The `hide()` should take effect after the if block is finished executing, but now it directly hides the element.

Comment: give `setTimeout()` something more than `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search-submit').on('click', function(){
    var keyword = $('#search-input').val();
    $(".loading").show();

    if(){
      //some conditions and calls to post
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".loading").hide();
    }, 1500);
  } 
}
```

Comment: at least say a few words about what you did here

Answer (score 1):

Actually, jQuery has a more refined way of making things synchronous :

```
$(function() {

    $('#search-submit').on('click', function(){

        var keyword = $('#search-input').val();

        $('.loading').show().queue(function() {

            if ( ... ) {
            //some conditions and calls to post
            }

            $(this).dequeue();

        }).queue(function() {

            $(this).hide().dequeue();
        });
    });
});
```